# Why FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView force http session creation

Tags: jsf

I have a filter which throw a ServletException in some usecases and web.xml is configured to show a jsf error page on that exception. I don't want at this stage that an http session is created. In debugging mode i see that FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView force a http session creation. Why?

Comment: Have you checked whether the previous one is invalidated? If yes, then a creation of new one makes sense

Comment: @Maciej There is no previous http session, it's the first request from a bot. Now i understood... The project uses server state saving method and the error page is a JSF page.

Comment: I agree it could be marked as duplicate